# Rails redirect_to is redirecting to https://subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, subdomain, cloudflare

I just set up cloudflare ssl on top of my website, and now whenever `redirect_to @thing` is called in rails the client redirects to `https://subdomain/thing/1` rather than `https://subdomain.domain.com/thing/1`. not sure if I need to change the cloudflare `A` records now that ssl is setup because the A record I had before `CNAME | subdomain | host` isn't working anymore. If any more information is necessary please let me know!

Rails server is started like so `rails s -p 3000 -b0.0.0.0 -e production`

DNS records are

`CNAME | subdomain | host
A     | domain    | serverip
A     | www       | serverip`

The rails server is running at `serverip:3000` and nginx is routing all traffic with the specific subdomain to this port. There are no redirect issues if everything is done using `serverip:3000`, but when I do actions using `subdomain.domain.com` the redirect issues reappear

nginx config
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://subdomain;
    }
}

upstream subdomain {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
```

```

Comment: set up your routes.rb properly - see here as an example: http://tomdallimore.com/blog/how-to-run-with-rails-setup-subdomains-in-your-routes/

Comment: I do not think this is a coding issue but more of a configuration issue with cloudflare. The rails server is running at `serverip:3000` and nginx is routing all traffic with the specific subdomain to this port. There are no redirect issues if everything is done using `serverip:3000`, but when I do actions using `subdomain.domain.com` the redirect issues reappear.

Answer (score 0):

you can add following changes `routes.rb`

```
constraints subdomain: false do
  get ':any', to: redirect(subdomain: 'www', path: '/%{any}'), any: /.*/
end
```

You can set the number of top-level domains as an argument to subdomain, e.g:

```
>> app.get('http://www.localhost')
>> app.request.subdomain
=> "" 
>> app.request.subdomain(0)
=> "www"
```

This can also be set in an environment file as well:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.action_dispatch.tld_length = 0
```

Comment: I do not think this is a coding issue but more of a configuration issue with cloudflare. The rails server is running at serverip:3000 and nginx is routing all traffic with the specific subdomain to this port. There are no redirect issues if everything is done using serverip:3000, but when I do actions using subdomain.domain.com the redirect issues reappear.